# Access a column only with a particular method in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, attr-accessor, attr-accessible

Suppose I have a model `User` with two attributes: `:name` and `:age`. I want the `:age` column to be accessible only to "def manipulate_age()"(some method). This also includes, `user.update_attributes!(:age => 10)` is expected to throw an exception. Is it possible to do that in Rails 3 way?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not list name and age in  attr_accessor, you cannot read and write those fields directly.